# Predicate expression at runtime

Tags: c#, xpath, predicate

In one of the projects I am working the functionalities of the system is based on certain business object properties. Now the condition of the business rules were expressed through LAMBDA expression. But the change to the condition is very frequent that I cannot rebuild the rules engine. So I opted to express rules as XPATH with business object processed in XML. This is working but, I want to know if there is any library or framework already available.

Comment: XPath support (at least some version) is built in to the framework. If you want to use C#-like syntax, maybe you could google for a "c# expression library" or something like that. But that's off topic, so voting toclose.

Comment: Yes that's what I have done. I mentioned it _already_ that business rules are expressed in `XPATH`. To parse the rules, I am serializing the business objects to `XML`, which I don't know the better way. So I was looking for any other option available.